# How to print the whole tag when parse XML file with python

Tags: python, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have a xml file like below:

```
<alarms rootMIB="1" source="PLATFORM">
<alarm alarmCode="123" alarmMIBName="chassde">
        <alarmObject>CHASSIS</alarmObject>
        <alarmType>equipmentAlarm</alarmType>
        <probableCause>equipmentMalfunction</probableCause>
        <description>Report</description>
</alarm>
</alarms>
```

And I can get the attribute of "alarmCode" and "alarmMIBName" by below code:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
for alarm_tag in dom.getElementsByTagName('alarm'):
    if alarm_tag.hasAttribute('alarmMIBName'):
            alarmmibname = str(alarm_tag.getAttribute('alarmMIBName'))
```

But I also want to **print the whole line that hasAttribute 'alarmMIBName',** that is the line:

```
<alarm alarmCode="123" alarmMIBName="chassde">
```

Could anyone tell me how to print the whole line? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried printing `alarm_tag` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. But alarm_tag is an object, I think it not works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
alarm_tag.toxml().split("\n")[0]
```

Comment: But when I tried with your method, I get the following error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @Vorsprung: I suppose that you mean `alarm_tag.toxml().split("\n")[0]`.